# Error al retornar una peticion POST AJAX en DJANGO

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, post

Tengo esta petición POST de JAX.

En el backend actualizo unos registros en la vista de Django , esto lo hace OK pero cuando devuelve da una error y no recarga la pagina.

**Este es el error:**

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0

**Este es el ajax:**

```
$.ajax({  
     headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },  
     "url": '/articulos/massup/',
     "type": "POST",  
     "dataType": "json",
     data: data,  
     success: function(e){  
    if(e="OK"){  
      location.reload(true);  
      }  
     },  
     error: function(a,b,c){  
      alert(c);  
     }  
    });  
   });
```

**Este es el view:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def massup(request):
    template_name = "articulos/articulos_ok.html"  
    contexto={}  
    if request.method=="GET":  
        cat = Articulos.objects.all().order_by("codigo")  
        contexto={"obj":cat}  
    if request.method=="POST":  
        codigos=request.POST.getlist("codigos[]")
        porcentaje = codigos[0]#el primer elemento de la lista es el porcentaje
        porcentaje=Decimal(porcentaje)
        codigos= [int(x) for x in codigos]#Convierte la lista en integer
        art_change = Articulos.objects.filter(pk__in=codigos)
        i=0
        for item in art_change:
            if i!=0: #Excluye el primer item ( el porcentaje)
                precioant=item.precio
                precionuevo=(precioant + (porcentaje * precioant/100))
                item.precio=precionuevo
                item.save()
            i=i+1
        return HttpResponse("OK")
    return render(request,template_name,contexto)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te fijas en tu petición AJAX estás diciendo que esperas una respuesta del tipo json por parte del servidor:

`"dataType": "json",`

Entonces lo que deberías hacer es mandar un JSON desde el servidor, o cambiar de tipo y mandar una respuesta de ese tipo en todo caso, pero te muestro un ejemplo de como mandarías una respuesta del tipo JSON:

En tu vista:

```
import json
# pon el import de la librerías mas arriba junto a tus otros imports
# ...
data = json.dumps({'status': 'OK'})
return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json", status=200)
```

En tu solicitud AJAX donde esperabas la respuesta:

```
// presta atención que en tu código original solo pusiste un solo signo de =
// eso lo que hace es asignar, si quieres comparar debes usar el doble == o 
// el triple ===
if(e.status === "OK") {  
  location.reload(); 
 // creo que lo querías hacer era recargar la página
 // la verdad la función reload no necesita de argumentos
}
```

Comment: Gracias @marcelob33 esta respeusta me srivio de mucho. Saludos